# Variable has been used before assigning a value?

Tags: vb.net-2010

Trying to resolve getting IP from host name but I get this warning on RetIP: 
(on Return RetIP line)
"Variable 'RetIP' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime."

```
Public Function GetIPFromHostname(ByRef Host As String) As System.Net.IPAddress()
    Dim IP As System.Net.IPHostEntry
    'Dim host As System.Net.IPHostEntry
    Dim RetIP As System.Net.IPAddress()
    Try
        'Host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByAddress(IP)
        IP = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Host)
        RetIP = IP.AddressList()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot resolve IP address from hostname ({0}) - {1}", Host, ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return RetIP
End Function
```

This code used to work in VB 2008 and 2010 but now doesn't work. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The warning is completely correct; if you didn't get it in 2008, it was due to a bug that Microsoft fixed.

If an exception is thrown, the variable will not be set.

Comment: I received the same error in VB 2008 and receive the same error now that I've upgraded to 2010. Do you know what the fix was? I've applied VB 2010 SP1. Thanks.